Segfault in JRE when trying to run Minecraft server
I've been running a Paper (1.21.3) jar, trying to host a Minecraft server on Oracle Linux Server 8.10. (29G RAM) Each time I run the jar, it'll successfully generate the world, then either

Immediately give a SIGSEGV error & core dump after generating world
Sit and be fine until a player joins, then give a SIGSEGV error & core dump


The steps I've been taking to run the .jar:

wget [Paper version]
(Tried with 1.21.3 unstable releases as well as 1.21.1 stable releases)
java -Xms4G -Xmx4G -jar server.jar nogui
(Tried with various -Xms ranging from 3G to 20G.)


Below is the full error message I got:
[22:29:49 INFO]: Done (48.297s)! For help, type "help"
[22:29:49 INFO]: Timings Reset
[22:33:07 INFO]: UUID of player bowosc is 2fdf21ec-0388-4f50-adf6-73b3c4d7m0f2
[22:33:08 INFO]: bowosc joined the game
[22:33:08 INFO]: bowosc[/MYIP] logged in with entity id 33 at ([world]3.5, 69.0, 5.5)
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f162b4b3ecf, pid=17317, tid=17359
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (23.0.1+11) (build 23.0.1+11-39)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.0.1+11-39, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [spark-cf69683bbb7-libasyncProfiler.so.tmp+0x6ecf]  NMethod::isNMethod()+0x1f
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h %e" (or dumping to /home/opc/core.17317)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/opc/hs_err_pid17317.log
[254.152s][warning][os] Loading hsdis library failed
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted (core dumped)

Why is this happening? How can I stop it from happening?

You are using Java 23. A quick google search recommends java versions 20-22 for mc 1.21, and recommends against using Java versions newer than what is required to run it. Considering the current latest LTS version of Java is 21, I'd recommend trying that.

Solved my problem by switching to Java 21. Thanks, Rishaan!
